# Distance function $\hat{f}(x,y)= |f(x)-f(y)|$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I am wondering, what is the necessary and sufficient condition for the function $\hat{f}(x,y)= |f(x)-f(y)| $ from $\mathbb{R}$ to  $\mathbb{R}$ to be a distance on  $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: You mean $f(x,y) = |g(x) - g(y)|$?
Like the $f$ at the start on two variables, is not the $f$ in side the absolute value. (That is a absolute value sign, right?)

Comment: 4 properties: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_%28mathematics%29#Definition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An obvious necessary condition is that $f$ is injective, because we want
$$
\hat{f}(x,y)=0\quad\text{if and only if}\quad x=y
$$
So from $|f(x)-f(y)|=0$, in other terms $f(x)=f(y)$, we need to be able to deduce $x=y$, which is precisely injectivity.

There is no problem for $\hat{f}(y,x)=\hat{f}(x,y)$, so we are left with the triangle inequality. Now
\begin{align}
\hat{f}(x,z)
&=|f(x)-f(z)|\\[4px]
&=|f(x)-f(y)+f(y)-f(z)|\\[4px]
&\le|f(x)-f(y)|+|f(y)-f(z)|\\[4px]
&=\hat{f}(x,y)+\hat{f}(y,z)
\end{align}
because of the standard triangle inequality for the absolute value.